# Which core-site.xml do I add my AWS access keys to?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I want to run Spark code on EC2 against data stored in my S3 bucket. According to both the [Spark EC2 documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) and the [Amazon S3 documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), I have to add my AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to the core-site.xml file. However, when I shell into my master EC2 node, I see several core-site.xml files.

```
$ find . -name core-site.xml
./mapreduce/conf/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/share/hadoop/templates/conf/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/src/packages/templates/conf/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/src/contrib/test/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/src/test/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs/tests/conf/core-site.xml
./persistent-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/share/hadoop/templates/conf/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/src/packages/templates/conf/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/src/contrib/test/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/src/test/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/src/c++/libhdfs/tests/conf/core-site.xml
./ephemeral-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml
./spark-ec2/templates/root/mapreduce/conf/core-site.xml
./spark-ec2/templates/root/persistent-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml
./spark-ec2/templates/root/ephemeral-hdfs/conf/core-site.xml
./spark-ec2/templates/root/spark/conf/core-site.xml
./spark/conf/core-site.xml
```

After some experimentation, I determined that I can access an s3n url like `s3n://mcneill-scratch/GR.txt` from Spark only if I add my credentials to both mapreduce/conf/core-site.xml and spark/conf/core-site.xml.

This seems wrong to me. It's not [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), and I can't find anything in the documentation that says you have to add your credentials to multiple files.

Is modifying multiple files the correct way to set of s3 credentials via core-site.xml? Is there documentation somewhere that explains this?

Answer (score -1):

`./spark/conf/core-site.xml` should be the right place